# Converting every pixel of TIFF file from decimal to binary

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, for-loop, save

I have a folder of `.tif`-files. I would like to convert every value in each of these files from decimal to binary. This code mostly works. The inner loop correctly outputs the binary equivalent for every value in the `.tif`-file. The outfile is also written to the output folder with the correct name and extension (`.tif`).

However, while *something* is being written to the output file (each one has a size of about 300 mb, comparable in size to the original `.tif`), the file cannot be opened in ArcGIS. When I try I get the error:

> Failed to add data, unsupported data type.

How can I properly save the output in `.tif` format to be accessible in ArcGIS?

I'm using Python 3.6.1 in the Jupypter notebook in ArcGIS Pro 2.5.

```py
import arcpy, os, glob
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = 0
arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "100%"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

input_ws = glob.glob(r'D:\MODIS_DOWNLOADS\Australia_500\QA\*.tif')
output_ws = r'D:\MODIS_DOWNLOADS\Australia_500\QA\BINARY'

for r in input_ws:
    basename = os.path.basename(r)
    r1 = arcpy.Raster(r)
    NUM_COLUMNS = arcpy.management.GetRasterProperties(in_raster=r1, property_type="COLUMNCOUNT", band_index="")[0]
    COLUMNS_1=int(NUM_COLUMNS)
    print(COLUMNS_1)
    NUM_ROWS= arcpy.management.GetRasterProperties(in_raster=r1, property_type="ROWCOUNT", band_index="")[0]
    ROWS_1=int(NUM_ROWS)
    print(ROWS_1)
    outname = "BINARY_"+basename
    print(outname)
    
    outfile= open(os.path.join(output_ws, outname),"w+")
    
    try:  
        for i in range (COLUMNS_1-1):
            for j in range (ROWS_1-1):
                if r1[i,j]>0:
                    H=(r1[i,j])
                    BINARY_RAW=bin(H)
                    BINARY_NEW=BINARY_RAW[2:]
                    outfile.write(BINARY_NEW)                
    finally:                
        outfile.close()
```

Similarly, I've tried solving this problem using the raster cell iterator, available beginning in ArcGIS Pro 2.5. This code runs and throws no errors, saving an output .tif file to the output folder. However, while the output file opens in ArcGIS Pro, the file is entirely made up of `NaN`.

```py
import arcpy, os, glob, numpy
from arcpy.sa import Raster, RasterCellIterator

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = 0
arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "100%"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

ws1 = glob.glob(r'D:\MODIS_DOWNLOADS\Australia_500\QA\*.tif')
outws = r'D:\MODIS_DOWNLOADS\Australia_500\QA\BINARY'

for r in ws1:
    basename = os.path.basename(r)
    r1 = arcpy.Raster(r)
    outname = "BINARY_"+basename
    print(outname)
    outRas=Raster(r1.getRasterInfo())    
    outRas.readOnly=False
    
    with RasterCellIterator({'rasters':[r1,outRas]}) as rci:
        for i,j in rci:
                if r1[i,j]>0:
                    H=(r1[i,j])
                    BINARY_RAW=bin(H)
                    BINARY_1=BINARY_RAW[2:]
                    BINARY_2=int(BINARY_1)
                    outRas[i,j]=BINARY_2
        outRas.save(os.path.join(outws, outname))
```

Comment: All geotiffs are binary regardless of datatype. Do you mean you want to convert from a floating point to 1 bit?

Comment: If you want to change data type, use the copy raster tool and set pixel type parameter to whatever data type you want, i.e. 1 bit. Or if it's the format you want to change (i.e. from GeoTIFF to raw binary) look at the raster to float or raster to other format tools.

Comment: The datatype and bit width are properties of the Tagged Image File Format (TIFF) structure.  You can't do binary substitution without also changing metadata or treat metadata as if it was a binary stream without corrupting the file. Some blocks are compressed, which means that altering in simple substitution will mangle them beyond recovery. If you're not prepared to learn the low-level TIFF format on an intimate basis, I'd recommend restricting yourself to using tools and libraries which are TIFF-aware.

Comment: For what it's worth to future readers, I was able to solve my problem in Matlab by converting the first code sample from Python to Matlab. The output data is correct in Matlab; I'm not sure why similar code failed to work in Python.